# Template operator overload is not picked up by linker

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, c++20

I have this minimal working example (I deliberately use `cstdio` here to keep `nm` output readable):

```
// main.cpp
#include "cstdio"
#include "foo.hpp"

int main() {
    Foo<int> foo{42};
    Foo<int> bar{42};

    bool b = foo == bar;
    printf("%d\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

```
// foo.hpp
#pragma once

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    Foo(T foo_) : foo{foo_} {}

    T foo;

    friend bool operator==(const Foo<T> &lhs, const Foo<T> &rhs);
};
```

```
// foo.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"

template<typename T>
bool operator==(const Foo<T> &lhs, const Foo<T> &rhs) {
    return false;
}

template struct Foo<int>;
template bool operator==(const Foo<int> &lhs, const Foo<int> &rhs);
```

And I build it like this:

```
clang --std=c++2a -lstdc++ main.cpp foo.cpp
```

It fails with

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator==(Foo<int> const&, Foo<int> const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main-3d7fff.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

despite I explicitly instantiated `operator==` template.

I have rebuilt each file separately:

```
clang --std=c++2a -c main.cpp
clang --std=c++2a -c foo.cpp
```

And explored both with `nm`:

```
main.o: 0000000000000060 T Foo<int>::Foo(int)
main.o: 0000000000000090 T Foo<int>::Foo(int)
main.o:                  U operator==(Foo<int> const&, Foo<int> const&)
main.o: 0000000000000000 T _main
main.o:                  U _printf
foo.o: 0000000000000020 T Foo<int>::Foo(int)
foo.o: 0000000000000000 T Foo<int>::Foo(int)
foo.o: 0000000000000050 T bool operator==<int>(Foo<int> const&, Foo<int> const&)
```

And despite that two signatures look compatible to me, when I try to link this, it fails:

```
$ ld -lc foo.o main.o 2>&1 | c++filt
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator==(Foo<int> const&, Foo<int> const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(short) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Why? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, asking the question had rubber duck effect. Compiler complaints, because it expects `friend bool operator==` to be a plain, non-template function, which it isn't — this can be seen by `main.o` expecting `operator==`, while `foo.o` exports `operator==<int>`.

In order to tell compiler that operator is a template on its own (implemented somewhere else), I had to change my `foo.hpp` as follows:

```
#pragma once

// forward declaration of Foo to use in forward declaration of operator== template
template<typename T> struct Foo;
// forward declaration of operator== template
template<typename T> bool operator==(const Foo<T> &lhs, const Foo<T> &rhs);

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    Foo(T foo_) : foo{foo_} {}

    T foo;

    // indicate operator== is some template
    friend bool operator==<>(const Foo<T> &lhs, const Foo<T> &rhs);
};
```

Now, `nm` produces expected output:

```
foo.o: 0000000000000050 T bool operator==<int>(Foo<int> const&, Foo<int> const&)
main.o:                  U bool operator==<int>(Foo<int> const&, Foo<int> const&)
```

Which makes it all link properly.

Comment: Huh, this is one case where gcc has a warning that clang doesn't. I could have sworn that I'd run into this before and gcc warned me (`warning: friend declaration 'bool operator==(const Foo<T>&, const Foo<T>&)' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]` with just -Wall)